# Sequential Group By in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compute the industry concentration of a portfolio using the [Herfindahl-Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herfindahl%E2%80%93Hirschman_Index) in SQL. My data contains the stock holdings at a certain point in time of a fund where each stock is linked to the industry depending on the issuing firm's business model. I want to implement the formula `\sum_{i=1}^N s_i^2`, see Wikipedia.

I set up a minimal example with toy data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cf423/1).

```sql
SELECT
    fdate, fund, SUM(ind_share * ind_share) as hfi
FROM (
  SELECT 
      a.fdate, a.fund, a.industry, SUM(amount)/b.fund_size AS ind_share 
  FROM holdings a
  JOIN (
      SELECT
          fdate, fund, SUM(amount) AS fund_size
      FROM 
          holdings 
      GROUP BY
          fdate, fund) b 
  ON 
      a.fdate = b.fdate AND a.fund = b.fund 
  GROUP BY fdate, fund, industry) AS T
GROUP BY fdate, fund
```

This solution is ugly because it requires many sub-queries. For an easier solution, I would like to sequentially perform `Group By` or assign a group sum to every group member.

Obviously, my dataset is much larger so I would like to optimize this code. Is there a more elegant solution without using sub-queries?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not intended as a slight, but I am not even sure how _"assign a group sum to every group member without aggregating it"_ is supposed to make sense.... since summing a group is aggregation.

Comment: It might have expressed myself poorly: I do not want to reduce the dataset to one row per group, but join a group-sum to every row / group member - without using a subquery. This would allow for an easier computation of the measure, I believe.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot get around using subqueries for this kind of calculation; any alternatives would mostly just be shuffling them around with minor adjustments. You probably get all the needed sums in one query with a _rollup_ modifier on the group by, but then you'd have to self join that query (making it a subquery), or do some convoluted aggregation on that query (also ending up with subqueries again).

Comment: Sad to hear that it does not get (significantly) more elegant than this. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is about as simple/succinct as it can get:

```
SELECT f.fdate, f.fund
   , SUM(POW(fundind_size/fund_size, 2)) as hfi
FROM  (
      SELECT fdate, fund, SUM(amount) AS fund_size
      FROM holdings 
      GROUP BY fdate, fund
  ) AS f
  JOIN 
  (
     SELECT fdate, fund, SUM(amount) fundind_size 
     FROM holdings
     GROUP BY fdate, fund, industry
  ) AS fi
  ON f.fdate = fi.fdate AND f.fund = fi.fund
GROUP BY f.fdate, f.fund
;
```

It's not much different than what you currently have, there are still three separate GROUPings, and two subqueries; but the subqueries are not quite as "deep" in this version.

*Note: The latest versions of MySQL have added "window" functions, and "windowing" for aggregate functions. I haven't had much need for them, but it is possible they could help in this scenario.*

Comment: Thank you for making the effort! It seems that performance is not much different, but maybe my test case is too small.

Comment: The best thing you could do for performance is to make sure `holdings` has a compound index on `(fdate, fund, industry)`, or a compound index of `(fund, fdate, industry)`.